# NHibernate Specify index on query

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I want to create Nhibernate C# query for below sql query,

```
SELECT ContactID
FROM Person.Contact WITH (INDEX(AK_Contact_rowguid))
GO
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the methode .CreateSqlQuery() like this exemple :

`var SessionFactory = Configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
ISession session = SessionFactory.OpenSession()
session.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT ContactID FROM Person.Contact WITH (INDEX(AK_Contact_rowguid))");`

for more information check this [link](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querysql.html)